# How to save and recover icon and folder positions?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, home-screen-folders

How can I save and recover the position of icons and folders?

They get wiped every time I patch Android.

Comment: Which device do you have? Version? Any particular home launcher?

Comment: Phones: Samsung Galaxy S II (2.33), SonyEricsson Xpedia X10 (2.1) Mini, Tablet: Advent Vega (2.2). I'm not using any home launchers on any of them - maybe I should!

Comment: Definitely give some a try.  Most 3rd-party launchers allow you to backup and restore their settings and desktop configurations (except for widgets, which is a limitation of the OS itself.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using LauncherPro go to your home screen, press `Menu -> Preferences ->Backup homescreen & settings` to backup and `Restore backup` is in the same place. This can't restore your widgets but remembers their places though. Also some app-specific shortcuts need to be recreated (in my case, shortcuts to K-9 Mail mailboxes).

Comment: In installed Launcher Pro and it was okay. Then I later restarted my phone and it wouldn't restart, so I have had to perform a factory reset :-((( Other people have had the same issue i.e. http://www.samsunggalaxysforum.com/samsung-galaxy-s-how-to/help!!-launcher-pro-crashed-locking-phone-in-black-screen-loop/ and http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-s/181912-my-samsung-galaxy-s-wont-start-up-help.html So I won't be installing that again :-(

Answer (score 4):

I am using [Go Launcher Ex](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex) Home launcher which saves the current configuration and we can restore it whenever we need. If you have a different launcher check for Backup/Restore configuration settings.